# Getting rid of rough edges after removing old paint

Tags: painting, sanding

I have an old weatherboard house.

Removed a lot of old, flaked paint recently from a relatively large section of the house above a rickety old garage. Because it wasn't the safest place to be, I was out of a lower grit paper for my orbital and as i'd been up there for two  days stripping, bogging and sanding some of the areas where I had removed old paint had not been completely feathered with the paint that remained. I primed it with two coats and these rough edges are noticeable when viewed up close (although not from the ground).

To get rid of these rough edges would I be best to sand the areas of concern with a lower grit and then reprime?

Comment: Best for normal people on the ground, or are you all that concerned with the up-close view few people will ever have...?

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, that's totally fine.  You do that all the time with restorative surface prep, alternating layers of epoxy primer, "bondo" (Abatron, West System ultralight filler etc.), sanding, primer, bondo, rinse wash repeat.

Though honestly, the best thing you can possibly do with a rickety old garage is stabilize it.  Why? Because stabilizing an old building is vastly cheaper than building a new one.  A new building, I swear, is 1/3 *entitlements* - fighting with the government for your right to build the building at all, all the extra junk you have to add to the new building's specifications to get approved - concrete foundation, AFCI breakers, trench new utilities to meet new code, *requiring a bathroom* for Pete's sake which means you must now plumb water and gas or much larger electrical so you can heat the building all year, sweet Nelly,  there's really no end to it.  It's a nightmare.  So yeah, if you ever foresee wanting a building this size, *save this one*.